# Getting order clause in .net project

Tags: mysql, .net, database

I'm using this scope:

```
      <%sc3="Select * From categories where id='" & idnum & "' order by id "
    set rc3=cc.execute(sc3)
    do while not rc3.eof%>
```

And it works. `id` is int11. But when I changed this to date column, its not work.

```
   <%sc3="Select * From categories where id='" & idnum & "' order by date ASC "
        set rc3=cc.execute(sc3)
        do while not rc3.eof%>
```

Its getting this error:

```
MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.5.44-cll-lve]Unknown column 'date' in 'order clause'
/pages/news.asp, line 311
```

It says unknown but I checked in phpmyadmin and has no problem:

```
SELECT * FROM `categories` ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: Try including the word date in backticks as phpmyadmin does: "Select * From categories where id='" & idnum & "' order by \`date` ASC "

Comment: @Shadow I tried this but contents not ordered by date, its mixed.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your response!

Comment: Your solution not working.

Comment: I'm sorry again, but your response does not indicate what error or unexpected behaviour you encounter. Therefore I cannot suggest any changes to my suggestion.

Comment: Presumably, `categories` does not have a column called `date`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, it has.